# Error: No visible @interface for 'XYZPerson' declares the selector 'saySomething'

Tags: objective-c

Searched through several threads but cannot find answer.

I am new to Objective-C and going through the briefer at apple development and experimented and keep getting the error: No visible @interface for  'XYZPerson' declares the selector 'saySomething'

The console program has an added Class called 
XYZPerson. Here are the .h and .m files:

This is the XYZPerson.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYZPerson : NSObject

@property (readonly) NSString *firstName;
@property (readonly) NSString *lastName;
@property (readonly) NSDate *dateOfBirth;

- (void)sayHello;
- (void)sayBooBoo;
- (void)saySomething;

+ (id)person;

@end
```

This is the XYZPerson.m file:

```
#import "XYZPerson.h"

@implementation XYZPerson

- (void)sayHello
{
    [self saySomething:@"Say Hello, World!"];
}

- (void)sayBooBoo
{
    [self saySomething:@"Say BooBoo, World!"];
}


- (void)saySomething:(NSString *)greeting
{
    NSLog(@"%@", greeting);
}
@end
```

Here is the code in main():

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XYZPerson.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World from Main!");

        XYZPerson *aPerson = [[XYZPerson alloc] init];

        [aPerson sayHello];
        [aPerson sayBooBoo];

        [aPerson saySomething:@"Something"];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

This causes a Build Failed. If I delete the line in main() " [aPerson saySomething:@"Something"];"

then the program will run with the following output:

```
013-05-14 15:38:04.102 XYZPerson[2303:303] Hello, World from Main!

2013-05-14 15:38:04.105 XYZPerson[2303:303] Say Hello, World!

2013-05-14 15:38:04.106 XYZPerson[2303:303] Say BooBoo, World!
```

Just cannot figure out why I can call the [aPerson sayHello] and [aPerson sayBooBoo] in main() but the [aPerson saySomething:@"Something."] causes a problem.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out in the comments, this exact same question has already been answered but to give you a quick answer, your .h has the method `- (void)saySomething;` while your .m requests an input parameter (an `NSString`) so you need to change saySomething in your .h to this:

```
- (void)saySomething:(NSString *)greeting
```

Which is the exact same signature you are using in your .m.

Because you have limited activity on StackOverFlow I just want to recommend doing a bit of research before posting questions. I am sure you did but it definitely benefits everyone if you are thorough in your search before posting questions on here.

Comment: Ah geez! Thanks! I guess I was thrown off because the call to "saySomething" by "sayHello" and "sayBooBoo" worked fine. Not sure why that is. Perhaps because "saySomething" is completely defined in the implementation itself. Perhaps the reason the outside entity "main()" threw the error because it "saySomething" was not completely defined in the XPZPerson header file.